# ConTeXt: Required environment variables in fish shell

Tags: context, linux

I installed ConTeXt according to the docs on my Linux machine and added the binary to my path, so I can run `context` from everywhere. If I do so I get the following errors:

```
mtxrun          | forcing cache reload
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '/home/domma/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '/etc/texmf/web2c' from specification '/etc/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c' from specification '/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '/usr/share/texmf/web2c' from specification '/usr/share/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c' from specification '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for regular 'texmfcnf.lua' on given path './share/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/share/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '/home/domma/texmf/web2c' from specification 'home:texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '/etc/texmf/web2c' from specification '/etc/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c' from specification '/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '/usr/share/texmf/web2c' from specification '/usr/share/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c' from specification '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving | looking for fallback 'contextcnf.lua' on given path './share/texmf/web2c' from specification 'selfautoparent:/share/texmf/web2c'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | warning: no lua configuration files found
resolvers       | resolving | no texmf paths are defined (using TEXMF)
resolvers       | resolving |
mtxrun          | the resolver databases are not present or outdated
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-context.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-contexts.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-context.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-t-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-contexts.lua' using hash 'lua::mtx-t-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-t-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'context.lua' using hash 'lua::context.lua'
mtxrun          | unknown script 'context.lua' or 'mtx-context.lua'
```

This is probably because I did not called `setuptex`. If I do so in a bash shell, everything works fine afterwards. My problem is: I'm using a Fish shell and there is no `setuptex` for Fish. The docs mentions some environment variable, but it is not clear to me which ones are really required and I don't want to guess based on the `setuptex`.

Can somebody tell me the minimal environment variables I have to set to get `context` working?

Comment: Does this [Containerfile](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite/blob/master/Containerfile) help shed any light (lines 48 to 52)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to Aditya's answer, the correct way to add this path to your `PATH` in fish is to run:

```sh
fish_add_path /opt/context/tex/texmf-linux-64/bin
```

With most shells, you would need to put an `export` command in your profile file, but with fish you only need to run that command a single time.

Comment: I marked this one as the solution, because it helped me solving the problem. I was not aware of `fish_add_path, but already configured the path in my config.fish. Looks like I was missing the trailing slash, which caused the trouble. After adding the slash it worked fine by just setting this one path.

Answer (score 2):

The only variable that you need to set is `$PATH`, which should be (change `/opt/context/tex/...` to the directory where you have installed context)

```
PATH=/opt/context/tex/texmf-linux-64/bin:$PATH
```

I also prefer to set TEXMFCACHE:

```
TEXMFCACHE=$HOME/.cache/context
```

It can be any directory which is writable by the user.